# Issue with C and Golang integration

Tags: c, go, dlopen, cgo

I have a C shared library named libtest.so which in turn use another shared library lihelp.so.
The code for libtest.so use dlopen() to load the libhelp.so

I have integrated libtest.so with my GO script gotest.go

When I run gotest.go after building and installing, I am seeing libtest.so is getting loaded successfully and function in libtest is executed successfully.
But the dlopen() call in libtest.so to load libhelp.so is failining with error "undefined symbol: dlopen"

But if I write a C application which use libtest.so all execution are fine withour any error.

Here is the code snippet of my Go file

```
/*
 #cgo CFLAGS: -I./include
 #cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ltest -ldl
*/
```

Here is the Makefile entry for building libtest.so

```
CC = gcc # C compiler
CFLAGS = -c -fPIC -I./include # C flags
LDFLAGS = -shared -L/lib -ldl # linking flags
```

Can any one suggest what can be the problem?

---

Output of ldd of my go binary

```
ldd app
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77c3000)
    libtest.so => ./libtest.so (0xb77bc000)
    libgo.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgo.so.5 (0xb6ed0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6eb2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6d03000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77c4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6ce7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6ca1000)
```

Comment: What is the output of running `ldd` on your go binary?

Comment: updated the output of ldd

Comment: Does this help? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/NPEKogRR9Q0/IC-IUUy7CQAJ

Comment: No it didn't help